# Role of 'by myself' in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I have difficulty in finding out which one is the object in this sentence:
"I learn much more by traveling by myself."
Can 'by myself' become the object in this case? Then 'by traveling' would be the complement?
Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

"By traveling [by myself]"
In that phrase, "by myself" is preposition phrase nested within another preposition phrase, acting as an adverb of manner, and modifying "traveling". It is equivalent to the adverb "alone".
The entire phrase "by traveling by myself" is also a preposition phrase acting as an adverb of manner, modifying "learn".